# Adding string to variable name

Tags: r

I have a variable `a=0.01`

I then create a matrix `b<-matrix(data=NA,ncol=2,nrow=9)`

I would like to rename this matrix by adding the value stored in `a` to its name.

The results should be `b_0.01`

Comment: What is your use case? I bet there is a better alternative to what you are trying to do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet there are more elegant ways to achieve what you need, but this seems to work:

```
assign(x = paste("b", a, sep = "_"), value = b)
```

**Edit following @Roland's comment:**

```
rm(b)
```

Please note that I address your question in a narrow sense. As pointed out by both @Roland and @Paul Hiemstra, there may be more general aspects of the work-flow that could be fruitful to consider as well.

Comment: But that is not renaming. You end up with two objects. I am not sure if a copy is made in memory immediately, but as soon as you modify the new object, you'll need twice the memory. At least include `rm(b)`.

Comment: @Roland, thanks for your comment! I add `rm`. I entirely agree that this is not renaming _per se_ - it was just my best alternative. I would be happy to see pure renaming solution. And yes, I support your comment to OP.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `assign` to get this done:

```
a = 0.01
b = matrix(data=NA,ncol=2,nrow=9)
assign(sprintf('b_%s', a), b)
b_0.01
```

In general, I would avoid creating data objects like this. In stead, I would use `list`'s to create, store and manipulate groups of objects.